# How to run audio file on android emulator?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I made a sample and try to run audio file but not able to run it. I don't know what's wrong with it but not able to figure out as it doesn't give me any error. I tried different example like tried to play .mp3 or .wav file also tried to run file from cache memory, run ApiDemos but yet no success with all. So does it related to emulator? Do I have to make any changes in emulator?

public class AudioDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
public int count = 0;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;  
Button toggleRain = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // load layout
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // load controls
    toggleRain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    // init player
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    // set click event handler
    toggleRain.setOnClickListener(this);
    // init state for playing
    count = 0;
}

@Override    
public void onClick(View toggleRain) {
    if(count == 0){
        mediaPlayer.start();
        count = 1;
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();                
        count = 0;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

}